# Disable Nodes & FPS Labels in Swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How would I remove the SpriteKit *nodes* and *fps*. I have tried looking through  `gameviewcontroller.swift` but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the lines:

```
skView.showsFPS = true
skView.showsNodeCount = true
```

from `GameViewController` since both those properties default to `false`.